# Use regex capturing group to extract tokens and store them in variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I have a shell script that reads an output string from the terminal that has the format:

> Book 2 Title (Chapter 1) [Page 2]

I want to grab the Title, Chapter, and Page and store them in variables like this:

```
TITLE="Book 2 Title"
CHAPTER="Chapter 1"
PAGENUMBER="Page 2"
```

Is there a shell command that allows me to use regex capturing groups to grab these tokens and store them in variables.

Note: So far I've looked into awk, but it separates the tokens by a space so it doesn't work for my case.

Comment: Anon, one suggestion: you might consider not using all-caps names for your own variables. All-caps variables may have meaning to the shell or system themselves -- for example: `DISPLAY` is used by the system, try  `echo "$DISPLAY"` on a terminal to check.

Answer (score 2):

```
s="Book 2 Title (Chapter 1) [Page 2]"
eval $(echo $s | sed  's/^/TITLE="/;s/(/";CHAPTER="/;s/) \[/";PAGENUMBER="/;s/\]/"/' )
echo $TITLE
echo $CHAPTER
echo $PAGENUMBER
```

Test

```
Book 2 Title
Chapter 1
Page 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this could be:

```
myString="Book 2 Title (Chapter 1) [Page 2]"
title="${myString%(*}"
chapter="$(echo "$myString" | cut -f2 -d'(' | cut -f1 -d')')"
pageNumber="$(echo "$myString" | cut -f2 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']')"
```

Output:

```
echo "$title" && echo "$chapter" && echo "$pageNumber"
Book 2 Title 
Chapter 1
Page 2
```

**Edit:** the "enhanced" version below would work even if the book title had one or more parenthesis or square brackets:

```
myString="Book 2 Title Foo (Revised Version) (1993) [abc publisher] (Chapter 1) [Page 2]"
title="${myString%(*}"
chapter="$(echo "$myString" | rev | cut -f2 -d ')' | cut -f1 -d'(' | rev)"
pageNumber="$(echo "$myString" | rev | cut -f2 -d ']' | cut -f1 -d'[' | rev)"
```

Output:

```
echo "$title" && echo "$chapter" && echo "$pageNumber"
Book 2 Title Foo (Revised Version) (1993) [abc publisher] 
Chapter 1
Page 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your line is store in a variable called "Line". The next step would be to "normalize" the content so it would be more easily parsable by commands (like a line from a CSV file).

Version 1: reformant the line so it would have 3 fields separated by "|" character. Then split the line so the variables would contain the required field value.

```
Line=$(echo "$Line" | sed "s/^\(.*\) (\(.*\)) \[\(.*\)]$/\1|\2|\3/")
# put the corect data to correct variables.
TITLE="${Line%%|*}"
CHAPTER="${Line%|*}"; CHAPTER="${CHAPTER#*|}"
PAGENUMBER="${Line##*|}"
# display the values
echo "$TITLE + $CHAPTER + $PAGENUMBER"
```

Version 2: using a regular expression mark the 3 fields and then prepare the commands to setup the variables. Use eval to really setup the variables.

```
eval $(echo "$Line" | sed "s/^\(.*\) (\(.*\)) \[\(.*\)]$/TITLE='\1' CHAPTER='\2' PAGENUMBER='\3'/")
echo "$TITLE + $CHAPTER + $PAGENUMBER"
```

Version 2 would be much easier to extend to any number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
Title=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}{ print $1;print $2;print $3}' filename )
chapter_tmp=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS="("}{ print $2}' filename)
chapter=$(echo $chapter_tmp | awk 'BEGIN {FS=")"}{ print $1}' )
pages_tmp=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS="["}{ print $2}'filename )
pages=$(echo $pages_tmp | awk 'BEGIN {FS="]"}{ print $1}'
```